# Installing XAMPP in Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, xampp, xfce4-terminal

I downloaded the XAMPP .run file from Apacheandfriends but the installation isn't working for me.

I can't seem to navigate to my downloads folder and it just keeps saying command not found all the time.

```
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# cd ~/downloads
    bash: cd: /root/downloads: No such file or directory
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# cd ~/Downloads
    bash: cd: /root/Downloads: No such file or directory
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# /downloads
    bash: /downloads: No such file or directory
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# cd /downloads
    bash: cd: /downloads: No such file or directory
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# cd downloads
    bash: cd: downloads: No such file or directory
    root@john-Aspire-V3-531:/home/john# downloads
    downloads: command not found
```

What do I need to do? Apacheandfriends says to:

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
```

and then

```
./xampp-linux-1.8.2-0-installer.run
```

but it doesn't seem to think that the file exists.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You are user root. The `~` is pointing to your root home. And root is not a desktop user so has no Downloads directory. So your 1st command fails because it needs to be `~/Downloads` and you need to be the normal desktop user.  To exit the root shell use `exit` or `logout`.

Please leave the root shell and issue these commands as your desktop user. It can and will break your system if you do this and use an malformed `rm`.

---

If part of the installation is to use root **please, stop using that software**. If that software has any backdoors or other stupidly coded software you could be opening your whole system to the world. And please use the [native LAMP stack](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). It is build and setup to work out of the box on Ubuntu, easier to setup and easier to maintain. It is as easy as issueing 4 commands and 1 password and you have a working apache and mysql with php installed.

Comment: To exit the root shell use `exit` or `logout` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Installing of LAMP may have some problems as like as some configurations problem with other applications also about auto updating of Apache, Mysql and PHP. You can install this packages very easy and without any additional suffer on Ubuntu. Please see [This link](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-9.10-lamp)

```
sudo su
aptitude install mysql-server mysql-client
aptitude install apache2
aptitude install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
aptitude search php5
aptitude install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do the following in terminal:

```
cd
```

(until you are left with only root@john-Aspire-V3-531:~$)
then

```
cd Downloads
sudo chmod 755 /xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
sudo chmod +x /xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.3-0-installer.run
```

I hope it works....
https://www.apachefriends.org/es/faq_linux.html